# Select from table where all array elements are in any of two fields

Tags: postgresql, select, join

I have two tables (one to many relationship) connected via a fkey. The first table contains the name of the records. The second table contains notes about the records. Obviously the tables have other fields too, but they don't have anything to do with the situation. The user inputs a string of keywords. The input is passed as an array **$keywords** to a function. In this function I would like to find those records that contain **all** the keywords. Some of the keywords may be found in the first table, others in the second. More specifically:

```
table family (family_id, family_lastname)
table members (member_id, family_id, member_firstname, notes)
```

**family_id** is p_key to **members** and f_key to **family**. **family_id** is p_key to **family**.

If i want to search for a person knowing part of his last name (because he may be Alejandro Gonzalez Inarritu, so I can search either by Gonzalez or Inarritu), or some other data in the notes field, then I would like to search in both fields - family_lastname and notes, to see if all the keywords belong to this person, and return his id (member_id).

I am pretty sure that you might have many questions like - why not create separate fields for the lastname and notes and so on, but knowing the full nature of the data, this is how it should be done.

I am posting the query so far, which, obviously does not work and is not even close to what I want to achieve.

```
SELECT member_id FROM members WHERE notes = %$keywords% OR family_id = (SELECT family_id FROM family WHERE family_lastname = %$keywords%);
```

This gets me the correct result if I only have one keyword. I would like to perform this query for every keyword and then join these results.

postgres version is 9.2++, so feel free to use any fancy functionalities. Also, I would appreciate not using any other tools besides the query itself (like functions for example). I want the whole job to be done in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join the two tables you could use **left join**. And to select from a list you can use the keyword **any**.

```
SELECT member_id FROM members m LEFT JOIN family f on f.family_id=m.family_id WHERE notes in ($keywords) and family_lastname in ($keywords);
```

Comment: But I do not need any of the keywords. I need all of them to be included, even if some of them are included in one of the tables and the rest in the other table.

Comment: in this case you have to use an in operator and "and" instead of "or" (see updated response)